# How do you make a vector of strings in for loop

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy, for-loop

How do convert a int array to a str array
input:

```
x = np.array([0,1,2,3....])
```

len(x)=73293

output:

```
y = np.array(["0","1","2","3"....])
```

We though about doing something like this:

```
y=[]
for i in range(len(x)):
        y=y.append(str(x[i]))
```

but it dosen´t work.

Comment: `y = [ str(i) for i in x] ` Note - don't have numpy, you'll have to verify if this works.

Comment: If you want to make it work with your for loop instead of a list comprehension, you should write `y.append(str(x[i]))` instead of `y=y.append(str(x[i]))`. append() adds the element to the list and returns None, so y will be None after the first iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
import numpy as np

#with list comprehension 
y = [str(x) for x in np.arange(73293)]

#if you prefer to use pure numpy
y = np.arange(73293).astype(np.str)
```

Also the pure numpy as much faster:

```
%timeit y = [str(x) for x in np.arange(73293)]
10 loops, best of 3: 87.3 ms per loop

%timeit y = np.arange(73293).astype(np.str)
100 loops, best of 3: 8.77 ms per loop
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [vectorize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html):

```
f = np.vectorize(lambda x:str(x))
f(x)
```

output :

```
array(['0', '1', '2', '3'], 
      dtype='<U1')
100000 loops, best of 3: 18 µs per loop
```

Edit :

```
f(np.arange(73293))

10 loops, best of 3: 30.3 ms per loop
```

Comment: Nice one! Didn't thought of that.

Comment: @Ding, Didn't know about np.str, thanks for the trick. : ) I'll have to look into that ! But it seem a bit slower than the builtin str, do you know it benefit ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use also [`np.apply_along_axis()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html) with a custom function like this example:

```
def my_func(a):
    return list(map(str, a))

a = np.array([0,1,2,3])
a = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: my_func(x), 0, a)
```

Output:

```
>>> a
array(['0', '1', '2', '3'], 
      dtype='<U1'
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved in pure Python:

```
>>> map(str, x)
['1', '2', '3']
```

Or if you need to convert back:

```
>>> x = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> np.array(map(str, x))
array(['1', '2', '3'], 
  dtype='|S7')
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you convert a matrix to a array/list of strings?
input:

```
M =   array([[1,1,2,5],
             [1,1,2,3],
             [1,2,0,4],
             [1,2,0,6],
             [1,2,0,8],
             [2,1,3,5],
             [2,2,9,6],
             [2,2,9,4]])
```

output:

```
N =   array(["1,1,2,5",
             "1,1,2,3",
             "1,2,0,4",
             "1,2,0,6",
             "1,2,0,8",
             "2,1,3,5",
             "2,2,9,6",
             "2,2,9,4"])
```

We have tried something like this:

```
list1=[]
for i in range(len(M)):
    list1=list1.append(str(M[i,0]),str(M[i,1]),str(M[i,2]),str(M[i,3]))
```